# jQuery animate affected by window.print() in Chrome?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, printing, jquery-animate

This is something only observable in chrome, none of the other browsers has this problem it seems.

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/DN9kQ/6/embedded/result/)

[Print Link Content](http://jsfiddle.net/y5Egb/)

Basically, I have a div containing bunch of items that I want to show, but only one at a time, so I created a div with overflow: hidden and default height. Now slap on jquery animate to loop to another div when the div is clicked, everything is working fine until I add the print link. If I click on the print link in the example page, it screws up the animate as long as the chrome print preview window stays open. As soon as I close the preview, everything goes back to normal. Anyone have any clue what's going on?

Comment: This really is rather strange, I think it would be appropriate to submit this issue to the [jQuery bug tracker](http://bugs.jquery.com/newticket)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but since it works with all other browsers, also when the print preview is not visible, I think this might have more to do with chrome than jquery?